# Calling a function using ng-submit with 'ControllerAs' syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using ng-submit, I am trying to call a function in my MainController. However, the function search is not being called. I am assuming i need to angularify my function but not sure how to.

index.html

```
<html ng-app="main">
    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
        <p>{{mainCtrl.message}}</p>

        <div>
            {{mainCtrl.error}}
        </div>

        <form ng-submit="search()">
            <input type="search" required placeholder="Username to find" ng-model="mainCtrl.username"/>
            <input type="Submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>

        <div>Name: {{mainCtrl.user.name}}</div>
        <div>Location: {{mainCtrl.user.location}}</div>
        <div>
            <img ng-src="{{mainCtrl.user.avatar_url}}" title="{{mainCtrl.user.name}}"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
(function() {       

    angular.module("main", [])
        .controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http",MainController]);

    function MainController($scope, $http) {

        function onUserComplete($response) {
            $scope.user = $response.data;
        };

        function onError(reason) {
            $scope.error = "Could not fetch the user";
        };

        function search() {
            $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + this.username)
                .then(onUserComplete, onError);
                console.log("1");
        };

        $scope = this;
        this.message = "GitHub viewer!";
        this.username = "angular";
    };
}());
```

Comment: `search` is not in `$scope`...

Comment: Because you used ... 'as' in ng-controller, you call it using mainCtrl.search(). https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

Comment: I changed it to mainCtrl.search() and it did not fix anything. Must be also something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have the search function in scope.

If you're using controller as syntax, there's a way you could go about it that will make things easier. You don't need $scope at all, actually.

Naming controller as vm in your controller and your view will keep things similar across concerns.

vm stands for view-model. [Check out this style guide by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), it really simplified my angular code and helped it make more sense.

Ignoring the style guide, a simple answer would be to add `vm.search()` instead of just `search()` to your `ng-submit`

`index.html`

```
<html ng-app="main">
    <head>`enter code here`
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainController as vm">
        <p>{{vm.message}}</p>

        <div>
            {{vm.error}}
        </div>

        <form ng-submit="vm.search()">
            <input type="search" required placeholder="Username to find" ng-model="vm.username"/>
            <input type="Submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>

        <div>Name: {{vm.user.name}}</div>
        <div>Location: {{vm.user.location}}</div>
        <div>
            <img ng-src="{{vm.user.avatar_url}}" title="{{vm.user.name}}"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`script.js`

```
(function() {       

    angular.module("main", [])
        .controller("MainController", ["$http", MainController]);

    function MainController($http) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.onUserComplete = onUserComplete;
        vm.onError = onError;
        vm.search = search;
        vm.message = "GitHub viewer!";
        vm.username = "angular";

        function onUserComplete($response) {
            vm.user = $response.data;
        };

        function onError(reason) {
            vm.error = "Could not fetch the user";
        };

        function search() {
            $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + vm.username)
                .then(onUserComplete, onError);
                console.log("1");
        };
    };
}());
```

There's a lot of stuff in that style guide that will simplify the way you write your angular code, its a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you so much. I do appreciate the style guide as I am just starting to learn AngularJS. Do you consider this a norm in angular? I am asking because I am trying to develop good habits and would like to start a early as possible. One thing I noticed in the code you gave me was  that the "MainController as vm". Would we name on other Controllers 'vm' as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what the norm is in angular. I've seen so many different ways of doing everything, it gets tough when you're looking up tutorials or through other people's code and everyone does it slightly different. I just saw a talk by the guy [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlvCbnKAH3g) and went with his suggestions because its very consistent and follows a lot of good basic JavaScript habits, and doesn't give a suggestion without a reason. And yeah, I've been using vm on every controller.